# How to assign the correct Itemid to manufacturer products page link form the product details page

Tags: php, hyperlink, joomla, product, virtuemart

I'm using Joomla! 3.10.6 and Virtuemart 3.8.9 with PHP 7.4.27.
In product details page I linked the manufacturer logo to the manufacturer products page, but the link Itemid is wrong.

Here is the code I implemented:

```
<?php 
if (VmConfig::get('show_manufacturers', 1) && !empty($this->product->virtuemart_manufacturer_id)) {
    JRequest::setVar('virtuemart_manufacturer_id',$this->product->virtuemart_manufacturer_id,'GET');
    $model = VmModel::getModel('manufacturer');
    if ($this->product->virtuemart_manufacturer_id !=0 ) {
        $manufacturer = $model->getManufacturer();
    $model->addImages($manufacturer, 1);
    $manlink = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=category&virtuemart_category_id=0&virtuemart_manufacturer_id='.$manufacturer->virtuemart_manufacturer_id, FALSE); 
        if (substr($manufacturer->images[0]->file_url, -1) !='/') { 
            $this->manufacturerImage = $manufacturer->images[0]->displayMediaThumb('class="manufacturer-image"', false);
        ?>
        <a class="manufacturer" href = "<?php echo $manlink; ?>"><?php echo $this->manufacturerImage; ?></a>
        <?php
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Like this the link Itemid is the same as the one in the product page. So it isn't the manufacturer menu Itemid.
Could you help me to create a code to auto assign the correct Itemid for the manufacturer menu? Thank you!

Comment: Please ask your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Done, thanks ->https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/32056/how-to-assign-the-correct-itemid-to-manufacturer-products-page-link-form-the-pro